# Algorithms for positioning objects in a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

Where can i find some algorithm to position some objects in canvas in a clever way? I'm using javascript (with Raphael svg library), but examples with other languages (or pseudo-language) are welcome. Geometry isn't my strong point =)

For example have 600x800 canvas, and i want to place *n* objects sized 60x60 in smart ways, for example:
- an algorithm to position objects along *m* concentric circles with *o* offset.
- an algorithm to position objects along *m* concentric squares, but an alternate frequency (the result can be like a chessboard)

And similar examples.. i'm just looking some working examples to adapt to my case. Thank you in advance =)

Comment: As far as I know, the performance of algorithms should be around O(n) for the chessboard question. (something like simple for-loop). I really look forward for any (if possible) faster solution

Comment: In my case, performance is not a critic argument. I have to manage only a limited number of object.

Comment: Coz I am not fully understand your questions about, maybe better you can upload an image of what is your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Circle:

Inputs: 
CenterPt(presumably 300,400), 
RadiusLargestCircle(presumably 270 to ensure your objects are all on screen)
RadiusDelta(60 ensures no overlapping objects assuming objects are circles)

calculate number of circles (  (RadiusLargestCircle -2*RadiusDelta) / RadiusDelta  )

for each circle

```
  RadCir= RadiusLargestCircle - (CircleNum*RadiusDelta)
```

(I'll finish this properly later, gotta head now)

but essentially first object centerpt goes at x=radiusLargestCircle, y=0

divide object 2*radius into circumferance of circle

for num objects

useing parametric equation of circle,
place object at x radians from previous one

next Circle